# Does function $f(z)=-i\sqrt{z}$ map unit disc to upper disc?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

I think that $\sqrt{z}$ is not defined on $[-1,0]$ , but this is the function I got as a result in problem to map conformally unit disc on upper unit disc...
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to our site! I've edited your question to improve readability. Please consider using MathJax notation in the future

Comment: @David Thank you! Because I'm new to this site I'm not sure how to write some things.For example,I know that sqrt stands for square root ,but I'm not sure what do I have to do so that the question looks like you did it...

Comment: Click "edit" to see how I wrote it. You can easily find documentation on MathJax.commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every complex number $z$, there are two possible "square roots". One of them is the opposite of the other. Your question depends on which one you are considering.

Comment: the problem sounds:Map conformly unit disc to upper unit disc. I know that w=(iz+i)/(1-z) maps unit disc to upper plane.Also,I know that w=(sqrt(z)+1)/(sqrt(z)-1) maps upper plane to upper unit disc.So their composition would have to be the function I'm looking for.I got that this composition is w=-i*sqrt(z) , but I'm not sure if that's ok... since sqrt(z)is not defined on [-1,0]

Comment: How do you define $\sqrt{z}$ for a complex number?

Comment: as the square root of its moduo * (cos(a+2k pi)/2  + i*sin(a+2k pi)/2) , where a=argument of that complex number , and k=0,1

Comment: OK. In that case we can see that the answer to your question is **no**. Take $z=i$ and check how $f(z)$ is not in the upper disc. The $\sqrt{}$ function does, though

Comment: I supposed that the answer is NO,but I don't see any mistakes in 'solving' this problem by composing those two functions I defined above ?!

Comment: There may be a language barrier preventing fluent communication here. What's your native tongue?

Comment: My native tongue is Albanian :)

Comment: There isn't a branch of $\sqrt z$ which is conformal on the unit disk, this doesn't depend on which branch you're considering. @Tota: taking the composition of $f = z \mapsto -i (z + 1)/(z - 1)$ and $g = z \mapsto (\sqrt z + 1)/(\sqrt z - 1)$ is a valid solution provided that you choose a branch correctly, the issue is that you evaluated $f(g(z))$ instead of $g(f(z))$.

Comment: @Maxim : Thanks a lot! But I didn't understand how it can be an issue that I evaluated $f(g(z))$ instead of $g(f(z))$ ...Shouldn't it be the same thing?